# Data structure to represent menu/taxonomy

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures

Is there a specific formal data structure that should be used when building a navigation, similar to a websites?

Or, are there any specific design patterns that are best suited to build such structures?  Composite looks promising

Answer (score 0):

For data structure you can use some variation of a graph (directed/undirected) and as far as design pattern, you need to describe a general behavior of the application in order to get a better answer but for fun I'll throw Singleton for you.

Comment: How will Singleton help? We specifically want the opposite, don't we?

Comment: @Dukeling Did you miss the `fun` word?

Comment: @MohitJain: The point is "as far as design pattern, you need to describe a general behavior of the application in order to get a better answer". I don't think it makes sense to recommend any pattern in my opinion because you cannot decide on a pattern solely based on a data structure you want to use, you need to describe the behavior of the application.